# A Successful Login

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, storyboard

The code below works but now when I push the login button, it automatically access me through to my next View Controller but I don't want that. I want to stay logged out until the correct information has been entered. I believe the problem is when I enter the storyboard and Appdelegate info before the login code. Any suggestion on how I would restructure this? or a more condense code?

```
 @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController




    let loginName = userNameField.text;
    let loginLast = userLastField.text;

    let loginNameStored = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loginName");

    let loginLastStored =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loginLast");

    if(loginNameStored == loginName)
    {
        if(loginLastStored == loginLast)
        {

            //login is successful

            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: in this code first you are setting a rootViewController and checking isUserLoggedIn ,right? . actually i don't understand what u really want can u explain it

Comment: @MidhunKMohan the idea is, once a user has successfully put in their username and password, they click the login button and it will take them to a view that has a tab controller. My problem is, when i click on the login button, it automatically sends me through to the next view without entering any login formation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try . I think the problem is first you are setting the `rootviewController` without any condition . It leads you to the next viewController . Also you want to check the `textField` `isEmpty` or not.

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

let loginName = userNameField.text;
let loginLast = userLastField.text;

let loginNameStored = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loginName");

let loginLastStored =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loginLast");

if(loginNameStored == loginName) && (loginLastStored == loginLast)
{
        //login is successful

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to place your login setters into a completion-block method and to call your `dismiss` method within the completion block. Like so:

**UPDATE** : Make sure to check if the `textFields` are nil.

```
 @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

    guard let loginName = userNameField.text, let loginLast = userLastField.text else { return }

    let loginNameStored = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loginName");

    let loginLastStored =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loginLast");



    if(loginNameStored == loginName)
    {
        if(loginLastStored == loginLast)
        {
            //login is successful
            appplySetters({
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
            })
            return
        }
    }
}

func applySetters(_ completion: @escaping(()->())) {       
   UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"isUserLoggedIn")
   if UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() {
      completion() // test synchronize here.. it acts as a proper delaying condition before calling completion.
   }
}
```

Code inside of completion blocks is only executed when their `escaping` parameters are called inside their functions. In this case, this parameter is called `completion`.

Comment: Everything looks good but the line "applySetters({" it's returning an error saying "Use of local variable 'applySetters' before it declaration"

Comment: Missing bracket was the solution but I still can push the login button to the next view without any user/password....should I add a breakpoint?

Comment: A possible issue here is that loginName loginNameStored  loginLastStored and loginLast can all be nil (`.text` and `.value(for..)`). so here if you press your button without running a `nil` check, technically your `dismiss` will execute as long as you have nothing present in your `textfield`s. I'll add some conditional guard statements, check out how to use them.

Comment: Your code unfortunately didn't work but I think it's a different issue. So the idea is once a user successfully puts in their username and password, the login button will take them to a view that includes a tab controller. I think the beginning code is the reason why the button is automatically sending me through without and user info.